# Как автоматически заменять нерабочую страницу на новую?

Tags: c#

использую библиотеку VkNet. прогружаю в текстБокс идентификаторы страниц в вк, которым нужно отправить сообщение. всё отправляется как надо, но! если у человека стоит ограничение(т.е. писать могут только друзья) то выбивается исключение и программа закрывается. как сделать так, что если нельзя отправить сообщение, бралась автоматически новая страница?

```
VkApi api = new VkApi();
int count=0;
api.Authorize(4562540, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, Settings.All); // авторизуемся - id приложения, логин, пароль, получаемые права доступа

string[] logins = textBox6.Lines;
for (int i = 0; i < logins.Length; i++)
{
    string id = logins[i];
    while (true)
    {
        if (count == 20)
            break;

        else
        textBox10.Text = api.Messages.Send(int.Parse(id), false, "привет, друг!").ToString(); // id - целое число
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрабатываем исключение и убираем бесконечный цикл `while`:

```
var api = new VkApi();
api.Authorize(4562540, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, Settings.All);

var index = 0;
foreach (var login in textBox6.Lines)
{
    try
    {
        var id = int.Parse(login);
        textBox10.Text = api.Messages.Send(id, false, "привет, друг!").ToString();
        if (index++ == 20) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(login);
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но при возникновении исключения работа программы ведь прекратится и сообщения перестанут отправляться? а я пытаюсь сделать так, что если нельзя отправить сообщение, то брать нового пользователя и отправлять ему

Comment: @АртёмКозинский Если возникает исключение  в методе `Send`, то исключение перехватывается и цикл по продолжает работать дальше. Также я убрал бесконечный цикл `while`. В нем не меняется `count`, поэтому выход из цикла не наступает.

Comment: а как сделать выход? ведь аккаунт может разослать ровно 20 сообщений людям, которых нет в друзьях

Comment: вернее, как остановить программу после 20-ого отправленного сообщения и оповестить об этом? чтоб например MessageBox появился с оповещением?

Comment: Вы хотите отправить сообщения 20 первым `logins`?

Comment: или остановиться после 20 успешных отправок?

Comment: желательно после 20 успешных отправок.

Comment: Добавил проверку на 20 успешных отправленных сообщений.

Comment: премного Вам благодарен. последний вопрос - как вывести идентификатор человека, на котором остановилась программа?

Comment: Добавил вывод в консоль последнего логина, которому было успешно отправлено сообщение.

Comment: странно, после того, как программа попадает на страницу которой нельзя отправить сообщение - пропускает сразу 3-4 страницы и только потом берёт другу, это можно как-то исправить? могу дать аккаунт для проверки и список людей для отправки сообщения.